# Setting EditText in popup equal to string of previous activity - Error:(92, 30) error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to String

Tags: java, android

So I am making this knittingcalculator app. based on a couple of inputs, the app outputs the result in a popup.
This is the code

```
public class Rectangular extends Activity {

EditText length;
EditText width;
EditText edge;
EditText roll;
TextView tt;
Button calculate;
double w=0;
double x=0;
double y=0;
double z=0;
double v=0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rectangular);
}



    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater
                = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


        Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.button9);
        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }});

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

    };





private void initControls()
{
    length=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    width=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    edge=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    roll=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    tt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    calculate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
    {public void onClick
                (View v) { calculate();}});
}

 EditText input;
 EditText output;
 Button one;


private void calculate()
{
    w=Double.parseDouble(length.getText().toString());
    x=Double.parseDouble(width.getText().toString());
    y=Double.parseDouble(edge.getText().toString());
    v=Double.parseDouble(roll.getText().toString());
    z=((x+y+y)*(y+y+w))/v;
    tt.setText(Double.toString(z));
}
```

xml(popup):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

 <View
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.4" />

 <EditText
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="numberDecimal"
     android:ems="10"
     android:id="@+id/editText6" />

 <View
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.15" />

 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/notice"
     android:id="@+id/textView7"
     android:textSize="18sp" />

 <View
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="1dp"
     android:layout_weight="0.05" />

 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/dones"
     android:id="@+id/button9"
     android:layout_gravity="right" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Now, the problem that I am having is I can't seem to set the edittext in the popup equal to the calculation and I hope someone can help me or pointme in the right direction

UPDATE:
So I got the editText to display the letter Z but I would like it to display the result, but when I do I get the exception of doubles cannot be converted to string at first line

```
private String result = (z);
 private void calculate()
{
    w=Double.parseDouble(length.getText().toString());
    x=Double.parseDouble(width.getText().toString());
    y=Double.parseDouble(edge.getText().toString());
    v=Double.parseDouble(roll.getText().toString());
    z=((x+y+y)*(y+y+w))/v;
    result = Double.toString(z);
}
```

any idea what to do?

Comment: If you want the result to be initialized to 0, then just set it to 0... `private String result = "0";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `EditText` is in your popup layout, you would have to find it through your inflated popup view.

```
EditText tt = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
```

And populate your `EditText` at the same time that you inflate the popup:

```
tt.setText(Double.toString(z));
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I set the EditText tt = (EditText) popupView.findViewById(R.id.editText6); & tt.setText(result); after the layout is built but it stays blank

Answer (score 0):

Set The PopupWindow property to set and edit the `EditText` value.

```
popupWindow.update();
popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
```